# How to send and receive gmail without app password using email password

Tags: python, imap-tools

I was wondering if there was a way to be able to use the email password to get emails from imap.gmail.com instead of making app passwords. If not is there a way to automate the process and request the user to accept terms and have the app password given rather than having users create one themselves?

Comment: what do u mean without app passwords?

Comment: Google implemented a security access code called an app password in order for applications to sign into accounts and access data but I wanted to know if there was a way to automate that for the end user rather than having it be a manually done process

Comment: oh i think this was possible before the last update. you could have less secure acount by giving a permission and could easily use it in python. now i think you need that app password.

Comment: I have seen some apps that show a request access browser window and then the user allows. Can Python do that and have one returned to it automatically?

Comment: there are two ways actually come in my mind. first, scraping ( like selenium) for automation browser based things. second, using your own cookie and signatures from your already logged-in adding to your requests and sending. both would work for simple tasks.

Comment: those apps you have seen probably using official APIs from google i think.

Comment: How would you appoach that @AminS

Comment: I haven't used selenium or worked with cookies in python

Comment: search for Selenium, Beautifulsoup, Requests modules. these are the things you need most. e.x search for automate linkedin login using selenium.

Comment: Use Google's SDK or API to send the email instead of a third-party. You could also transfer your email to a difference service which may make it easier for you to send emails.